# Does Google insist on using Wallet exclusively, or can my app offer both Wallet and PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal, android-pay

I have apps on Google play that use in-app billing. Google wants you to use their Wallet. I have seen articles stating things like: "Google forcing Android developers to use Google Wallet for in-app payments"

Okay, I will use Google Wallet. But, what they don't say, and I can't find via searches, is whether Google insists on using Wallet **exclusively** or whether I can offer both Wallet and PayPal. Other articles have indicated that people don't like using Wallet for some reason.

Can anybody offer insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears to me that you can not use anything but the Market's payment processor (Google Wallet).  I'm not a lawyer, and this advice is worth everything that you paid for it though.

See [this thread](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile/paypal-app-model-android-legal-android-market#answer-186985) for some details.

People (myself included) don't like Google's in-app purchase system because they made it ridiculously hard and convoluted to implement.